# Deploy in to jboss EAP 6.4 from jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jboss, devops, jboss-eap-6

I wanted to deploy in to jboss eap from jenkins.I have configured a job which pulls the artifact from nexus repository in to workspace using repository connector plugin.I wanted to do the deployment in to jboss EAP from jenkins.Is there any way i can acheive it?

I think one way could be to use the jboss-as-maven-plugin.is there any way i could tell jboss-as-maven-plugin to take the war from workspace location?

is there any other option available?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure maven plugin like as:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>7.9.Final</version>
<configuration>
    <execute-commands>
        <commands>
            <command>deploy target/core-services.war</command>
    </execute-commands>
     <hostname>localhost</hostname>
     <username>{your username}</username>
     <password>{your passwprd}</password>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```