# Deploy war on jboss using jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jboss7.x

I have one ec2 instance where jboss is running and another ec2 instance where jenkins is installed.My war is built in jenkins.Now i want to deploy it on jboss on another EC2 instance.SO we used deploy on container plugin as post build action. We have given management console url and credentials.But atter running job we are getting below error:

**ERROR**

> 17:58:24 Deploying /../../../../some.war to container JBoss 7.x Remote
>   with context somewar 17:58:29   The undeployment phase of the redeploy
>   action has failed: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot
>   undeploy deployable
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.WAR[some.war] 17:58:34 ERROR:
>   Build step failed with exception 17:58:34
>   org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot deploy deployable
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.WAR[some.war] 17:58:34    at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:216)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy(AbstractDeployer.java:245)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
>   17:58:34  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078) 17:58:34     at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061) 17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
>   17:58:34  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1843) 17:58:34     at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>   17:58:34  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429) 17:58:34
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://soemhost:9999. The
>   connection timed out 17:58:34     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:113)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.java:47)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.AbstractServerDeploymentManager.execute(AbstractServerDeploymentManager.java:79)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.executeAction(JBossDeployer.java:144)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.deploy(JBossDeployer.java:84)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:212)
>   17:58:34  ... 18 more 17:58:34 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException:
>   JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://somehost:9999. The
>   connection timed out 17:58:34     at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolChannelClient.connectSync(ProtocolChannelClient.java:155)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementClientChannelStrategy$Establishing.getChannel(ManagementClientChannelStrategy.java:166)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:137)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:62)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:106)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:89)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:252)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:151)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:111)
>   17:58:34  ... 23 more 17:58:34 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to
>   remote://somehost:9999. The connection timed out 17:58:34     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:113)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.java:47)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.AbstractServerDeploymentManager.execute(AbstractServerDeploymentManager.java:79)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.executeAction(JBossDeployer.java:144)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.deploy(JBossDeployer.java:84)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:212)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.redeploy(AbstractDeployer.java:245)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
>   17:58:34  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078) 17:58:34     at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061) 17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
>   17:58:34  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1843) 17:58:34     at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
>   17:58:34  at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>   17:58:34  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429) 17:58:34
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to
>   remote://somehost:9999. The connection timed out 17:58:34     at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolChannelClient.connectSync(ProtocolChannelClient.java:155)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementClientChannelStrategy$Establishing.getChannel(ManagementClientChannelStrategy.java:166)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:137)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:62)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:106)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:89)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:252)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:151)
>   17:58:34  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:111)

Comment: What is "deploy on container plugin"? Are you trying to deploy the war using  a kind of deployment endpoint provided by jboss server?

Comment: no there is one post build action Deploy to container where you can select server and give server details like username password server url and war will be deployed to that container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the firewall rules, because Jenkins does not connect to the remote host (Could not connect to remote http://somehost:9999).

Another way to do deploy is to use a shell script over ssh, like [this](https://gist.github.com/chrisweibel/1945437)

Comment: after configuring in jenkins,its taking default port as 9999 though we have configured  different port and from chrome we are able to access management console...but from jenkins its throwing error

Comment: Could you please see the connection via telnet?
`$ telnet <your-ip-address> 9999`
Or you can try the Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/WildFly+Deployer+Plugin.

Comment: actually my management console is <ipaddress> 9990 ,but still its taking port as 9999

Comment: You can try with maven plugin. Ser this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48292131

Comment: and we are using jboss 7